# BluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices returns zero Devices although paired, why?

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

I'm currently trying to write an Android App which connects to a Device using Bluetooth and opens a serial connection. To connect to the device I need to pass the device to some Code which establishes and maintains the connection. My Problem is that I don't seem to get to this point because my code always returns a NullPointer as device.

I've already tried debugging the code and now found out that the function to get bonded devices returns zero devices. To mitigate this I've made sure that the bluetooth adapter is existent and is turned on. I've also made sure in the android menu that there are devices connected and that the android device I want to establish a connection to has been paired with.

Below is the code which should identify and return the device:

```
public class BluetoothDeviceRecognition {
BluetoothDevice blDevice(BluetoothAdapter myBluetoothAdapter) {


    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = myBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    BluetoothDevice myDevice = null;
    if(pairedDevices.size() > 0){
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices){
            if (device.getName().equals("ESP32_LED_Control")) {
                myDevice = device;

            }
        }
    }
    return myDevice;
}
```

This is the Code which should make sure that there is a bluetooth adapter and which should enable it if this is not the case:

```
    public void startBluetooth(){
    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "connectBluetooth: Does not have Bluetooth Capabilities");
        return;
    }
    if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "connectBluetooth: Enabling Bluetooth");
        Intent enableBTIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivity(enableBTIntent);
    }
}
```

And this is the code which starts the code above:

```
        connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            try{
                startBluetooth();
                BluetoothDevice myDevice = mBluetoothDevice.blDevice(mBluetoothAdapter);

                connectBluetooth(myDevice, MY_UUID_INSECURE);
            }
            catch(NullPointerException e){
                Log.d(TAG, "connectBluetooth: Bluetooth Device cannot be Null");
                sent.setText("Error, Bluetooth Device cannot be Null");
            }


        }
    });
```

When setting a break point at the beginning of the if loop in the first code snippet, I expect to have the size of the pairedDevices be greater than 0 but the actual size of the pairedDevices is zero.

EDIT:

My Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My Target SDK should be 21.

EDIT:
So I didn't really solve this but instead used a different approach. Instead of looking for devices which were paired with my device I am instead looking for devices which are currently discoverable near me. Used this code: https://github.com/mitchtabian/Sending-and-Receiving-Data-with-Bluetooth

Comment: Can you show your Manifest and the Target Sdk you have specified ?

Answer (score 0):

Before calling mBluetoothDevice.blDevice(mBluetoothAdapter), you must make sure that bluetooth has been turned on. So you just need to use startActivityForResult(enableBTIntent) to enable bluetooth and receive the result from onActivityResult(), once you receive the reslut that user turns on bluetooth, you can call mBluetoothDevice.blDevice(mBluetoothAdapter).

Comment: The Application does not enter the if loop to enable Bluetooth as Bluetooth has been turned on. I just checked with Breakpoints to make sure

Answer (score 0):

You are Missing The Location Permission,

As Stated in the Documentation : 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#Permissions

If your target Sdk is 23 and higher, you should ask for this Permission at runtime

Comment: I added Coarse and Fine Location to manifest but it did not change anything. And if I'm crrect I did choose SDK 21 as target, so this should not apply.

Comment: Check that the Permission are granted to the App(in the App info on the device)